# Tag Synonym voting

Tags: discussion

Just curious if people aren't voting because they can't on the suggested combinations, (I voted for the only one I could) or they don't care either way on the current list  or they don't even know about the list to look at/for it?

we have 6 open for voting and I've been expecting some kind of movement (up or down).

Or is it too early to seriously think about combining any tags yet?

Mostly I'm looking for what my reasonable expectations should be.

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

EDT: Just thought I'd bump this, we have two sets of tags that should have enough people to make a decision one way or the other, just wanted people to remember to take a look now and then.

Comment: I think the "map-making"←"cartography" synonym goes in the wrong direction. How to vote that?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I would tend to reverse it as well, though most people use map-making not cartography.

Answer (score 2):

I've been active reviewing tag edits (and making a few myself), but I didn't know about the tag synonym voting. Thanks for bringing it to the attention of everyone who didn't know about it (unless that's just me!). I've tried to suggest synonyms before, but I learned that you need a score of at least 5 (I think) in the tag to suggest a synonym. That may contribute to a lack of participation, especially among the rarer tags.

I followed the link, by the way, but I was unable to vote on the synonyms (despite the fact that I'd like to). How do we go about doing that?

Comment: You need to click on one, I think usually the left one, then it takes you to the tag page and there is a little voting spot shows up.  However, you still need I think a score of 5 in one of the tags to vote on it.  Just try voting it will tell you if you have enough.

Comment: BTW, part of the reason for the question was because I thought this might be the case, people just don't know.

Comment: Hey, it worked! I don't have 5 score in environment/ecology, but I was able to vote. Awesome.

Comment: Whoops, look like you do have to have 5 score to vote. Curses.

Comment: I can't vote on anything :(

Comment: We might have to wait a while to get all the suggested synonyms approved, because everyone with 5 score+ might not have the required rep (1250, for some reason) to vote. This might take some time. . .

Comment: Yes, it's not meant to be easy.  Just answer more questions!  ;)

Comment: In that case, anyone want to suggest a [tag:science-based] synonym? :-)

Comment: @HDE226868  It looks like you only need 1250 rep to propose a synonym.  To vote you just need a net score of +5.